# How to show mysql database from java web service using c#

Tags: c#, java, mysql, web-services

I've created a web service using Java (Netbeans IDE). The web service is a web service with MySQL database. and now I want to create a client application using C# Windows Form (Visual Studio IDE). I've added a web reference (wsdl link) on a client project. but I am confused about how to display the records from my database on my C# Windows Form.

Need help pleaseee,,, thx before...

Answer (score 0):

You should add a service for get a value in your web service.for example `GetData` and in c# call the service.
Every service returns a specific type for example `List<>` or a class like `Person`.